# Latexdiff error (caused by multi paragraph \sout): Paragraph ended before \UL@on was complete

Tags: errors, latexdiff

I try to use latexdiff to point out changes I have made in a document to the other people who need to read it and give me their advice... However, I've been getting this error:

```
Runaway argument?
{En rajoutant aux interactions la seconde main, qui dans notre cas es\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \UL@on was complete.
<to be read again> 
               \par 
l.8 }
   %DIFDELCMD <
?
```

regarding this section of code produced by latexdiff :

```
 \DIFdelbegin \DIFdel{En rajoutant aux interactions la seconde main, qui dans notre cas est la main gauche, l'interface pourrait devenir plus intuitive et plus facile à utiliser.

}%DIFDELCMD < 

%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdelend
```

Where `\DIFdelbegin`, `\DIFdel`, `\DIFdelend` are defined as (in my main .tex, added automagically by latexdiff) :

```
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\protect\color{red}\sout{#1}}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{} %DIF PREAMBLE
```

What's wrong & what can I do now?

EDIT : If I replace the `\sout{#1}` by just `#1` (i.e., remove the strike-through formatting), it works, but that strike-through kinda was the best feature of it, making it easy to spot what was removed. Is there another formatting command that would not break with a new paragraph?

If there was a strikethrough environment I could probably use it (by placing a `\begin{strikethrough}` in `\DIFdelbegin` and an `\end{strikethrough}` in `\DIFdelend`), but I don't think there is one.

Comment: If you remove the blank line in the argument to `\DIFdel`, does the error persist?

Comment: No, but that's part of the problem. Latex diff is inserting this line automatically, I can't be editing all my files manually after latexdiff has parsed them, I'd rather look for another solution than be forced to do it manually.

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem. Latexdiff seems to introduce Windows line endings, which seemed to caused the problem.

I now run dos2unix on the resulting latexdiff tex files and the problem has disappeared.

I'm running latexdiff 0.5 (Algorithm::Diff 1.15 so)

Comment: Awesome, I'll make sure to try that.

Comment: I had the same issue and this worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

I got the same problem when I was doing difflatex in Mac. The exact same error ! What I did was moved up the `"}"` sign that was causing the problem to the the end of the paragraph and it worked. Don't ask me why, but it worked for me !!!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `\sout`, try the `\st` command from the [soul](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/soul) package.

Comment: In my case, neither `\sout` nor `\st` work, even if I use the packages.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked defining a new command `hsout` according to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246971/more-robust-strike-through-cross-out), which takes care of having multiple paragraphs in the command `sout` from the package `ulem`. Also using the definitions for `\DIFadd` and `\DIFdel` which take care of the using the `color` command for multiple paragraphs as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207225/writing-paragraphs-in-textcolor), `{\color{<color>}{...}}`

```
\RequirePackage{color} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\newcommand\hsout[1]{\let\helpcmd\sout\parhelp#1\par\relax\relax} %<-- new command
  \long\def\parhelp#1\par#2\relax{%
    \helpcmd{#1}\ifx\relax#2\else\par\parhelp#2\relax\fi%
  }
\providecommand{\DIFadd}[1]{{\color{blue}{#1}}}       %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdel}[1]{{\color{red}\hsout{#1}}}  %DIF PREAMBLE
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem caused by the `\hspace` inserted after citation commands, unfortunately the other answers here didn't help. For a quick and relatively sane workaround, modifying the "safe commands" list of `latexdiff` works pretty well. In my case, adding this option has fixed it:

```
latexdiff --exclude-safecmd='cite,citep,citet'   [....]
```