# Writing paragraphs in \textcolor

Tags: color

I want to write a document where a paragraph or two has a different text colour. I am using the \textcolor environment for this. But here is the problem

when I write

```
 \textcolor{red}{blah blah blah}
```

everything is fine.

But when I try this

```
 \textcolor{red}{blah blah 

 % A paragraph here 

 blah blah }
```

Then the colour disappears.

EDIT: Here is a MWE:

```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{color}
  \begin{document}
  \textcolor{red}{blah blah blah}


 However 

 \textcolor{red}{blah blah 

  blah blah} 
 No color in this case.

 \end{document}
```

I am sure I am making some simple mistake. Any help is appreciated. 
[image: Here is the output]

Comment: Could you bring us a full MWE?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your comment ...MWE?

Comment: I mean a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I take it you ignored the error your MWE produces?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`\textcolor{<color>}{...}` is a *command* that doesn't allow changes of paragraph (it is defined with `\def` instead of `\long\def`).

You must use `{\color{<color>}...}` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{showframe} % Only for demo
\begin{document}
\textcolor{red}{blah blah blah} 

{\color{blue}blah blah 

 % A paragraph here 

 blah blah}

blah blah 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Just for info.. are their any cases where \textcolor is more favorable than {\color}?

Comment: You probably mean `\long\def` and not `\edef`.

Comment: @egreg Yes, thanks. I meant `\long\def`, fixed.

Answer (score 15):

I would recommend you define you own environment for paragraphs that are in color:

[image]

### References

- As per egreg's comment, there needs to be a `\leavevmode`. See [How does changing colour affect spacing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47050/how-does-changing-colour-affect-spacing).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newenvironment{MyColorPar}[1]{%
    \leavevmode\color{#1}\ignorespaces%
}{%
}%

\begin{document}
Normal text preceding.

\begin{MyColorPar}{red}
blah blah 

A paragraph here 

 blah blah
\end{MyColorPar}

Normal text following.
\end{document}
```

Comment: My impression is that this should be `\leavevmode\color{#1}\ignorespaces`, because of the well known problems of starting a new color in vertical mode. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47050/how-does-changing-colour-affect-spacing, for example

Comment: @egreg: Your impression?  Really, _just_ an impression? :-) Thanks for the correction.

Comment: After adapting the \newenvironment to another problem, I found that, if the last line of the last paragraph reaches the right margin, an extra line is added. The solution given at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/673970/187997 is to add \unskip; that is, change `}{%` to `}{\unskip%`.