# \newcommand, par and textcolor

Tags: macros, color, paragraphs

OK. I read [What's the difference between \newcommand and \newcommand*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1050/whats-the-difference-between-newcommand-and-newcommand). However, when I try using

```
\definecolor{cincinnati-red}{RGB}{190,0,0}

\newcommand{\authorA}[1]{\textcolor{cincinnati-red}{[A: #1]}}
```

in this form:

```
\authorA{
    Hi Guys:

    (more stuff)
}
```

I get the error

```
Runaway argument?
{[A:  Hi Guys: 
! Paragraph ended before \@textcolor was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.166 }
```

How do I set up this macro so that the textcolor extends over the entire scope of the argument? (Simply changing \textcolor to \color, as suggested when reading [Writing paragraphs in \textcolor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207225/writing-paragraphs-in-textcolor), does not work for me. (The color does not show up.)

Comment: Don't use \textcolor. It doesn't accept a paragraph in its argument. Use  \color. If if doesn't work for you: Make a *complete* example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  `\color` is the correct command to use.

Answer (score 3):

The correct command here is `\color` as `\textcolor` is not long.  The syntax for your command would then be

```
\newcommand{\authorA}[1]{{\color{cincinnati-red}[A: #1]}}
```

not that that `\color` and the text it applies to is enclosed in an extra group of braces, so the color does not affect the text following the command.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{cincinnati-red}{RGB}{190,0,0}

\newcommand{\authorA}[1]{{\color{cincinnati-red}[A: #1]}}

\begin{document}

Text before

\authorA{
    Hi Guys:

    (more stuff)
}

Text after
\end{document}
```